# Socket.io not working in Ionic Android build

Tags: android, ionic-framework, socket.io

I'm trying to create an Android app with Ionic to send messages to a Node.js server. I'm using `socket.io@2.3.0` for the server and `socket.io-client@2.3.0` for the Ionic app. The Ionic app is supposed to open a `socket.io` connection with the server, then send the message `"Hello, World!"`. The Ionic app build for the web works properly, I tried running it from other devices (my laptop and my phone) and in both cases the socket.io connection worked and the server printed out the message received from the Ionic app.

```
// Server output
Server running on port 5000.
New connection from 7rI7qvo9gNjVD5ElAAAA
Hello, World!
```

But when I build the Ionic app for Android using the commands:

```
ionic cap add android
ionic cap open android
```

And then debug from Android Studio, the app launches, but I don't see any message from the server, and I don't even see an error message in the Android Studio debug tab.

```
// Server output
Server running on port 5000.
```

At first I thought this was a network problem so I made sure the `AndroidManifest.xml` file included the permissions `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`, I tried building an APK and running it on my phone, but it still doesn't work so I don't know what I should do.

I'm using the version 5.4.16 of Ionic.

Thanks for reading this, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by hosting the Node.js server on Heroku, now everything works fine, I'm not sure why though. Since the protocol changes from http to https when I host the server on Heroku, I'm guessing Android doesn't like the http protocol.